# Best practice for multiple user types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website. In my system there are around 5 types of users with different properties and each of them should have their own control panel which will give them tools to handle their work on the system.

Now I understand there are 2 approaches I could take (or maybe even a better alternative)

1. Use the `ApplicationUser` as the base class for all of them such as:

   ```
   public class NormalUser : ApplicationUser
   {
   }
   ```

and retrieve the ones I want like this: `var users = db.Users.OfType<NormalUser>();` However I understand that this will combine all of the properties of different user types onto the same table and it could potentially be a huge table.

2. Use the `ApplicationUser` as a property of each user type and handle everything manually. This obviously could be a little tedious but maybe a bit tidy.

Is there a 3rd and better approach and if not which one is the go-to approach for web developers? Because I imagine this is a pretty common need on various websites.

Comment: There is a concept of `Roles` within ASP.NET Identity.  Assign each user type a Role and then customise the user experience based on whether a user is a member of one or more of your defined roles.  The ways that you have suggested at the moment aren't very maintainable, you are essentially suggesting that you need a new database table for each user type.  You're not making use of your relational database that way.

Comment: @Luke I'm familiar with the `Roles` however I don't think that would be enough for my needs. I need to store different data based on each type of user.

Comment: For instance I need to store employees previous work records but I don't need them for my normal users.

Comment: In that instance, make it so that your application doesn't record the employee previous work items for a specific role?  I worry that the solution you are proposing means that you will be storing your user data in multiple database tables, that doesn't (necessarily) make sense in a relational database.

Comment: The way you application works shouldn't necessarily affect the structure of your database.  If you have two types or user, this usually doesn't mean you need two entirely different database tables.  Perhaps you should consider having one user table and multiple tables that store data specific to each user type.

Comment: @Luke I'm confused. Wouldn't what you're suggesting basically be the same as my 2nd approach? Using that, I would store the data specific to each type of user on its table and just add a reference as a foreign key to the `ApplicationUser` record.

Comment: Your user types shouldn't dictate your table structure.  It should be normalized as such that data is not stored in multiple places.  To take your example of 'previous work items', no matter whether you need to store 'previous work items' for one or many user types, you would only ever have one table for 'previous work items` and refer to the users within that table from the primary key (IE the user `Id`).